# Revision number is not updated properly in VNext builds

Tags: tfs, build-definition, vnext

Working with Gated/CI build definition (vNext) in TFS2017, the revision number is not increased correctly. Each build has the same Rev number even the changes are checked-in properly.

I get the revision number from $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER via powershell at the beginning of the build process and it always returns the same number.

Comment: Do you mean the build number always the same? How did you set the `Build number format` in your build definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the `$(Rev:.r)` token in the `Build number format` setting.

> [**Build number format:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/pipelines/build/options?view=vsts#build-number-format)
>
> Use **$(Rev:.r)** to ensure that every completed build has a unique name.
>   When a build is completed, **if nothing else in the build number has
>   changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one**.
>
> If you want to show prefix zeros in the number, you can add additional
>   '**r**' characters. For example, specify **$(rev:.rr)** if you want the Rev
>   number to begin with 01, 02, and so on.

Also make sure the build number was not updated with the permanent number or string. (There is a possibility that [used a script to customize your build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts) that updated the build number)

---

**UPDATE1:**

Please note that if the Major build number is changed in `Build number format`, then the revision number will not be changed. **The Revision number only incremented when the Major part is not changed.**

BTW,  the token `$(rev:.rr)` should be used such as a variable, so the build number format should be something like : `Test DEV CI_Rev.$(rev:.rr)` in your scenario.

---

**UPDATE2:**

In your scenario you updated the build number with the assembly info every time. So, if the assembly info is different every time, then the revision number will no be changed, that's the expected behavior.

[image]

Comment: My Build number format is: `Test DEV CI_Rev.(rev:.rr)`

But I update the build number by **Test 1.8.0.8 DEV CI.01**


I've created a variable like "Test Ver DEV CI.Rev" where "Ver" is replaced with AssemblyInfo and "Rev" with Revision number.

Reading the above information, the revision only change if "Build number format" does not change, am I correct?

Comment: @Felipe Yes, if the Major build number is changed in `Build number format`, then the revision number will not be changed. The Revision number only incremented when the Major part is not changed. BTW,  the $(rev:.rr) should be used such as a variable, so the build number  format should be something like : `Test DEV CI_Rev.$(rev:.rr)` in your scenario.

Comment: @Felipe Please see the updated answer, especially for the **bold** words.

Comment: sorry I already had $(rev:.rr). But what do you mean with "Major part", because you can put anything that you want.

Comment: @Felipe  The "Major part" means the major build number, for example assume the final build number is `2018Test.1`, then the major part I mentioned should be `2018Test`. When you use the token `$(rev:.r)`, if the build number `2018Test` is not changed next time, then the next final build number should be `2018Test.2`. But if the build number `2018Test` is changed, e.g changed to `2018Test-v`, then the revision  will not be changed any more, the final build number maybe  `2018Test-v.1`

Comment: Thanks, now I understand better. In my case is changed everytime due the update of the assembly. But this approach is different than XAML builds where the revision changed in each build independently of the major part.